# Invoking an Add-in from an actionable card with Outlook desktop client for mac

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I recently worked with actionable messages in Outlook and tried to use the Action `Action.InvokeAddInCommand` to open a task pane from within the card. This concept as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/invoke-add-in#resources) worked well when using the Windows desktop client or the web browser. But when using the desktop client for Mac nothing happens when clicking the button of the actionable card.
Actionable cards itself as well as the task pane of the add-in work without a problem. Just the connection between the two doesn't seem to function. Has anybody came across this problem or is this a known issue? I couldn't find anything regarding the compatibility of this explicit feature.